# Optional Command Line Parameter in Python

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

I am trying to retrieve optional command line parameters for a Python script (2.7 under Windows) and things are not going smoothly. The code is:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = 'Process display arguments')
parser.add_argument('-t', nargs = '?', default = 'baz')
args = parser.parse_args(['-t'])
print args.t
```

If I run "`program.py`" with no parameter, args.t is printed as None.
If I run "`program.py -t`", args.t is printed as None.
If I run "`program.py -t foo`", args.t is printed as None.

Why am I not getting the value from the command line into args.t?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't pass `['-t']` to parse_args. Just do:

```
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Any arguments you pass to parse_args are used instead of your command-line. So with that argument it doesn't matter what command-line you use, argparse never sees it.

Comment: And '-h' now works as well! I think I got confused when the examples moved from "print parser.parse_args([ '-t']" to actually using it in the script.

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
args = parser.parse_args(["-t"])
```

is passing the command line arguments ["-t"] to the parser. You want to work with the actual command line arguments, so change the line to

```
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [const keyword argument](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#const):

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = 'Process display arguments')
parser.add_argument('-t', nargs = '?', const = 'baz', default = 'baz')
args = parser.parse_args()
print args.t
```

Running it yields:

```
% test.py          # handled by `default`
baz
% test.py -t       # handled by `const`
baz
% test.py -t blah
blah
```

Comment: This is explained in the documentation: Note that for optional arguments, there is an additional case - the option string is present but not followed by a command-line arg. In this case the value from const will be produced.